# PHP SVM - Feature engineering

Tags: php, machine-learning, svm, feature-extraction

We have data for people going to school. Things like previous education level. Interests. Gender. Military status.

How do we convert these to integer/float values so we can throw them into an SVM model? Am I going about this the right way?

Side note, is the PHP SVM module an ok thing for just doing some simple modeling? Or is it not worth using?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using this data?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The answer is to make matrices out of the options. So gender would become male and female as 2 separate columns, each with their own 0/1 value.